# Web application UI examples

Tags: user-interface

I am currently prototyping a line of business application for the company I work for. It will be web based written in ASP.Net.

I am looking for some web application UI examples to give me some creative ideas to jump start the UI design and layout.

More info...

Case management, task management with work flow, basic accounting features for payment transactions, reporting and logging just to name a few features. Our company manages diversion programs for state and district attorneys so we are dealing with monitoring offenders and seeing that they complete the program requirements within a set time frame.

Comment: You probably need to at least specify the business domain to make any suggestions more useful.

Comment: yes - more info - otherwise "look at the internet" might be a good start.

Comment: Randy, I'm not even sure that is an intelligent comment? If a client asks you to build a "Line of Business Application" is the first thing that comes to your mind "Word Press" or "Joomla" or maybe "OS Commerce"?